# What information exactly is in the access control bits of a page table?

Tags: kernel, memory, virtual-memory

I'm currently learning for an exam in operating systems. This includes learning some basics about page tables, which lead me to the question [Why using hierarchical page tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9834542/562769) which mentions that access control bits take about one byte for each entry in the page table. [Another source](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cs333/notes/virtual_memory4.pdf) mentioned also one byte for one page.

But what information is in access control bits for a hierarchical page table?

[tfinley.net](http://www.tfinley.net/notes/cps104/virtual.html) mentions:

- Valid bit
- Dirty bit
- Do we have access to read (but why should we ever not have access to read?)
- write
- execute

That would be 5 bit. But I don't think the source is good and I still miss 3 bit.

According to [Gary Shute](http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/os/address-translation.xhtml#page-table-entries) it's 4 bit additional information (valid bit, rwx).

Could somebody please tell me what's in the access control bits? Preferably with a source.

I guess this question might depend on the actual system. I'm happy with any system you know this for and have sources.

Comment: Ah, I think I might have found an answer: [Paging in de-wiki](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Reales_Beispiel:_IA32-Architektur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for a IA-32 architecture. I took the information form [Intels IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), Page [1751](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf#page=1751)/3044(!):

Table 4-6. Format of a 32-Bit Page-Table Entry that Maps a 4-KByte Page:

- 0 (P): Present; must be 1 to map a 4-KByte page
- 1 (R/W): Read/write; if 0, writes may not be allowed to the 4-KByte page referenced by this entry (see Section 4.6)
- 2 (U/S): User/supervisor; if 0, user-mode accesses are not allowed to the 4-KByte page referenced by this entry (see Section 
  4.6)
- 3 (PWT): Page-level write-through; indirectly determines the memory type used to access the 4-KByte page referenced by this 
  entry (see Section 4.9)
  entry (see Section 4.9)
- 4 (PCD): Page-level cache disable; indirectly determines the memory type used to access the 4-KByte page referenced by this 
  entry (see Section 4.9)
- 5 (A): Accessed; indicates whether software has accessed the 4-KByte page referenced by this entry (see Section 4.8)
- 6 (D): Dirty; indicates whether software has written to the 4-KByte page referenced by this entry (see Section 4.8)
- 7 (PAT): If the PAT is supported, indirectly determines the memory type used to access the 4-KByte page referenced by this 
  entry (see Section 4.9.2); otherwise, reserved (must be 0)
- 8 (G): Global; if CR4.PGE = 1, determines whether the translation is global (see Section 4.10); ignored otherwise
- 11:9: Ignored
- 31:12: Physical address of the 4-KByte page referenced by this entry